# How to extend a system partition in a dual boot setup?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (x64) LTS (from  Windows 7) in a dual boot setup.

I allocated 30 GB disk space for Ubuntu is, now it's full.

How can I extend the disk space available to Ubuntu beyond 30 GB?

Answer (score 1):

You can boot into a live session and use `gparted` to resize the partition. Make sure you backup your data first. I have done this quite a few times with no errors at all but better safe than sorry.

You can download a GParted live CD [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).